# Ansible URI Module and ServiceNow Attachment API

Tags: ansible, attachment, servicenow-rest-api

[I have used Ansible with URI module to attach a PDF or CSV file to an existing incident and it gets attached with no issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77311365/6771046).

But when I try to download the same attachment, either the CSV is garbled or encrypted or PDF says, cannot be loaded. Please see the code and the error below.

Ansible code to upload a CSV or PDF file

```yaml
            - name: "Attach output CSV file to incident"
              ansible.builtin.uri:
                      url: "{{ SN_HOST }}api/now/attachment/upload" 
                      user: "{{ SN_USERNAME }}"
                      password: "{{ SN_PASSWORD }}"
                      method: POST
                      return_content: true
                      validate_certs: false
                      force_basic_auth: no
                      status_code: 201
                      body_format: form-multipart
                      headers:
                          Accept: 'application/json'
                          Content-Type: 'multipart/form-data'
                      body:
                        table_name:
                            content: incident
                        table_sys_id:
                            content: 'c6957640470388444c736d4315'
                        uploadFile:
                            filename: "../../win_playbooks/reports/User_Manual.pdf"
              register: attach_file
```

Error when trying to open the attached PDF file

[image]

Error when trying to open the downloaded attached CSV file

[image]

When I use the ServiceNow REST API explorer or the ServiceNow UI manually to upload and download the attached PDF or CSV file, it works perfectly. I guess the issue is that, when I try to upload the PDF or CSV from the above mentioned Ansible code, it is not working.

Comment: The content of your text file seems obviously  Base64 encoded. In plain Ansible you could check the content via something like `{{ CSV_file_content | b64decode }}`. This leads to the [`body_format`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-body_format), "_The serialization format of the body. When set to `json`, `form-multipart`, or `form-urlencoded`, encodes the body argument, if needed ..._" which might need to ne addressed.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is base64 encoded. Is there any way to stop auto encoding getting done within Ansible? (like inside the headers section, 
I tried like this headers:
```lang-yml
           headers:
                          Accept: "application/json, chartset=' '"
```
Still the above approach did not worked.

Comment: Unfortunately; I haven't an answer yet. Since I have access to such environment(s) and I am interested in an answer too I might be able to test such, but that will take significant amount time.

Comment: @U880D, As a temporary fix, I directly used CURL command inside Ansible task which does not encode any file when attached to a serviceNow incident record. I believe the behavior of the ansible URI module which when used with ```body_format: form-multipart``` will auto encode with base64(charset=UTF-8) and at present, there is no way to bypass encoding with this body format. So CURL is the only option for now.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix, I directly used `curl` command inside an Ansible task which does not encode any file when attached to a ServiceNow Incident Record.

I believe the behavior of the Ansible `uri` module which when used with `body_format: form-multipart` will auto encode with base64 (charset=UTF-8) and at present, it seems there is no way to bypass encoding with this body format.

> *[`body_format`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-body_format), "The serialization format of the body. When set to json, form-multipart, or form-urlencoded, encodes the body argument, if needed ...*"

So `curl` is the only option for now.